# Backing up Subscriptions in Reporting Services 2005

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, subscriptions

Is there a way to back up the subscriptions i have created on my reporting services server?

I store the reports in a source control and it would be nice to back up the subscription aswell incase something happens to the server and they are lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All SSRS data (reports, datasources, folder, security, subscriptions the lot) is stored in the ReportServer database. If you back this up, then you're OK.

Having your solution in source control is good too, but to recreate the SSRS set up is easier with a restore.

Saying that, the *scheduling* of subscriptions is via normal SQL Server jobs so you'll need msdb backed up too on the metadata SQL Server instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Follow up question, is it possible to duplicate subscriptions to identical reports? I have a test folder and a live folder containing the same reports just different data sources. I have created all the subscriptions on test and would now like them on live. The only change in the subscription is obviously the report (dev -> live) and the email address to subscription gets sent to. Is there an easier way than just recreating them manually?